# How to use Codeigniter db connection in non-CI class

Tags: database, codeigniter, pdo

I have a php class that requires a PDO instance to be passed to it's constructor. The code would be something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO($host, $username, $password);
$myclass = new myClass($pdo);
```

The problem I've got is integrating this with CI. CI auto loads it's database class which handles all DB connections and is accessed with

```
 $this->db->
```

It would be very simple if I was able to instantiate myClass with the CI database object, but it seems to contain a lot more stuff than just the PDO instance. I've tried

```
 $myClass = new myClass($this->db);
```

and it doesn't like it at all. I realise I could rewrite myClass to access the CI db object directly (i.e. without having to have a new connection passed to it), but I don't really want to start that mammoth undertaking!

So, is there a way to use the CI db class for this purpose? Would it make any difference if I just created a new PDO instance as above if the CI database library is already loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to get the current PDO connection from CI's database class. However, you don't necessarily need that. You can create your own PDO connection and pass that in to your custom class. You'll have two live connections to the DB, which isn't ideal, but you could probably work that out.

Comment: Thanks swatkins, that's kinda what I thought. I was trying to avoid having two connections cos it just seemed a bit daft! I think I might end up rewriting the class...